# Integrate JGroups with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jgroups, axon

I want to pass my messages (JSON strings) ActiveMQ using JGroups. Has anyone done this before? I am not able to find any example or sample code to start with. My main challenge is the design. So far, this is my design[image: design for the system]

Is my design correct? It would be great if I get any sample code for the same.

Comment: U shouldn't integrate jgroup framwork and activemq ,such as like mybatis and jpa.

Comment: Are you talking about message groups?

Comment: @RookieCy thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. although i found a situation where jgroups and activemq are used in same ecosystem (http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-topologies.html - Peer to Peer). But according to my use-case, peer to peer communication is not something i want.